# How to generate price comparison report in the mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dated brent prices table that keeps a price list from 1 January to 31 January. I want to compare the price for the 1th of January 2020 (or other date) with the first of January 2021 (or other date), The report will have date, year like 2020 and 2021 with the prices for 2020 displaying under 2020 and the prices for 2021 displaying under 2021.I have written the below query but it does not.

```
SELECT b.date
     , b1.price as year1
     , b2.price as year2 
  from brentprices as b 
  join brentprices as b1 
    on b1.year = '2020'
  join brentprices as b2 
    on b2.year = '2021'
```

Below is the sample table and data

[image]

Below is the expected result

[image]

Comment: Because you do no have the prices for the year 2021?   Please also add some sample data, en desired output.

Comment: Also, you do not (want) to compare prices from the year 2020 with the year 2021. What you really want is to compare the price for the 1th of January 2020 (or other date) with the first of January 2021 (or other date), and that piece is missing from your query!

Comment: (Also, you do not (want) to compare prices from the year 2020 with the year 2021. What you really want is to compare the price for the 1th of January 2020 (or other date) with the first of January 2021 (or other date), and that piece is missing from your query!) 

YES THIS IS WHAT I WANT PLEASE @LUUK

Comment: Luuk, below is what I want to achieve:

 I want to compare the price for the 1th of January 2020 (or other date) with the first of January 2021 (or other date), The report will have date, year like 2020 and 2021 with the prices for 2020 displaying under 2020 and the prices for 2021 displaying under 2021

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. How is the rest of the date stored, apart from the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabular text` and `images` are different... (but that's another discussion):

```
create table brentprices (date date primary key, price decimal(8.2));

insert into brentprices values ('2020-01-01', 100);
insert into brentprices values ('2020-01-02', 101);
insert into brentprices values ('2020-01-03', 102);
insert into brentprices values ('2021-01-01',  99);
insert into brentprices values ('2021-01-02', 103);
insert into brentprices values ('2021-01-03', 102);

select * 
from brentprices b1 
left join brentprices b2 on b2.date=date_add(b1.date,INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
where year(b1.date)=2020;
```

output:

```
+------------+-------+------------+-------+
| date       | price | date       | price |
+------------+-------+------------+-------+
| 2020-01-01 |   100 | 2021-01-01 |    99 |
| 2020-01-02 |   101 | 2021-01-02 |   103 |
| 2020-01-03 |   102 | 2021-01-03 |   102 |
+------------+-------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: This is not working. I need three columns for the result. Date, 2020, 2021 with the prices for 2020 under 2020 and the prices for 2021 under 2021

Comment: You can change the query yourself, or not? it is a question of copy it into an editor, and make the changes where needed. Or should we explain here how that works too? i do think you should not stop thinking, and provide some input yourself to solve YOUR problem.